# External yml file in Spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter

My requirement is to read an external yml file(property file) in Spring boot(version 2.6.6) and spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap version 3.1.1  application which I kept in a location /usr/IN/application-DEV.yml(This yml I placed at ths location)

- Created a @Configuration class and create a @Bean of **PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer** method but seems it is not working for yml file

For example: I kept yml file in my local system C drive

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
{
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer prop = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
prop.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/usr/IN/application-DEV.yml"));
return prop;
}
```

`Error Logs: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \usr\IN\application-DEV.yml`

Comment: Can you please share what the logs are showing? is it not finding the active spring profile or maybe not scanning the bean? also in Windows you should use "\" in the paths.

Comment: Are you using spring cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

a simpler alternative perhaps - in your `application.yml` just reference the external yml file:

```
config:
  import: 'file:/tmp/foo/bar.yml'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer 
 propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new 
   PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocations(
            new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\a.yml")    );
    return configurer;
 }
}
```

`a.yml` is `name: lant`.
This is my code ,it works well, and i can get the config by

```
@Value("${name}")
String name;
```

I cannot determine the specific reason based on your description.
Also there is another way,you can use `@PropertySource`.
For example there is `C:\Users\user\Desktop\a.yml`,and the content of the file is `name: lant`

```
@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource("file:C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\a.yml")
public class ExternalPropertiesConfig {
  @Value("${name}")
  private String name;
}

@Autowired
ExternalPropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;

String name = propertiesConfig.getName();
```